# How can I refresh a webform with F5 without being affected by a postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Let's say in my webform I have just triggered (for instance OnClick) an event that generated a postback from the server.

So that event is submitting info to the server thus generating a postback.

If the webform is submitted only 1 time, whenever I hit F5 on the browser, the server will postaback the last "postback" form it sent which means **the webform is automatically resent to the server thus triggering that postback**.

I can verify it on my webform and session variables by seeing redundant information.

I can deal at server side code with redundant data to minimise the effect of postback.

But what I'd like to do is to "catch" the F5 action in a method as server side and **completly** restore my webform and any other session variable manually.

How can I catch F5 ?

**NB** : I have already used `IsPostBack` but I want to specifically catch F5

Comment: You can do this with setting some bool value to decide whether its a refresh or postback by some control.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid I don't want to use a control. I have already used `IsPostback` BUT I want to specifically catch F5

Comment: [Have you tried this?](https://forums.asp.net/t/1779114.aspx?Check+whether+a+Page+is+first+loading+or+refreshing+)

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid Yes I did... But here, **the problem is that once the form is submitted**, F5 will always make `IsPostBack` = `true`.  Don't forget that other events (controls) can also trigger a postback. That's why I want to specifically catch F5